# 0-1 knapsack problem with additional capacity

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, approximation-algorithms

The [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition) maximizes the profits of items under a capacity constraint (let's call this capacity $C$).

I am interested in an augmented setting where the algorithm is permitted to use a larger knapsack with capacity $C' \geq C$, but it is required to obtain at least the optimal profit of a knapsack with capacity $C$.

My questions are two fold:

- Can every $\rho$-approximation ($\rho < 1)$ algorithm to the 0-1 knapsack problem obtain the optimal profit with a knapsack having $(1/\rho) C $ capacity?
- If not, does there exist an approximation to the 0-1 knapsack problem but can also solve the augmented case with a bound on the additional capacity?